# Using Lift within a larger web application

Tags: jakarta-ee, lift

I understand that Lift is implemented as a servlet filter and so it should in principle be possible to embed it within a legacy web application. Can anyone give me a HOWTO on this? Everything I've found so far is about developing a self-contained Lift app, using Maven and/or sbt to generate a magic skeleton for you.

I'd like to know exactly what dependencies I need to add to my existing web app; I suppose I could trawl through the archetype-generated POM files and web.xml and try to reverse engineer them, but surely someone must have done this already? And where (in this larger-webapp scenario) should I be putting my Lift templates and resources and so on?

Comment: Did you ever end up doing this? Answering your own question would be of great help to me right now...

Comment: No, I wasn't able to get far enough on it in the available time and ended up crossing Lift off the list of platforms to prototype.

Comment: That's too bad. I am continually amazed at how clean Lift makes things. I just wrote a completely interactive webapp with full database access and AJAX interfaces in a pretty tiny amount of code. I am amazed at how well it all works together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is the answer for the processing chain:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/liftweb/QCNHkFzyNw4

and as far as dependencies go, my list in sbt (which is similar to maven) is:

```
"net.liftweb"             %% "lift-webkit"        % liftVersion        % "compile",
"net.liftmodules"         %% "lift-jquery-module" % (liftVersion + "-2.0"),
"javax.servlet"           % "servlet-api" % "2.5" % "provided->default",
"org.eclipse.jetty"       % "jetty-webapp"        % "8.1.7.v20120910"  % "container,test",
"postgresql"              % "postgresql"          % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4",
"com.mchange"             % "c3p0"                % "0.9.2-pre6",
"org.squeryl"             %% "squeryl"            % "0.9.5-2",
"org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016"    % "container,test" artifacts Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar"),
"ch.qos.logback"          % "logback-classic"     % "1.0.6",
```